# .NET VSTO 'RibbonControlSize' is abiguous error

Tags: .net, vb.net, vsto

I created a project in VBA and ventured into VS2015 to create a simple 2010 VSTO Outlook ribbon button to open the file.  Everything worked fine a couple months ago when I created it, but now I went in to change the file location and I'm getting the two following errors. From what I've found it looks like RibbonControlSize is used in MS Office 2013+, but this is for 2010.  If I right click on a Reference and select View In Object Browser then I see a reference for Office[14.0.0.0] and Office[15.0.0.0], which both come and go with the reference to Microsoft.Office.Core.  Any ideas on how to fix this??

This is the line causing the issue.

```
Me.button1.ControlSize = 
Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge
```

Errors are....

```
Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize'.  Are you missing an assembly reference?  
'RibbonControlSize' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Core'
```

**UPDATE**

The add-in is being built using .NET framework 4.0 with Office 14 Object references, however the Office[15.0.0.0] is being added automatically and I've found others with similar errors related the file below, but no solutions...  GAC_MSIL\Office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll

Answer (score 0):

`Office[14.0.0.0]` are meant for Office 2010

`Office[15.0.0.0]` are meant for Office 2013

That said since you need 2013+ delete version 14 of dll.

Links:

[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx)

[2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0049f33-857b-41d9-895b-d52a022353b6/office-interop-assemblies-2013?forum=exceldev)

All Microsoft commercial products numbers don't align with programming versions.

Windows 7 for example has version 6.1

Comment: I can't remove just the Office[15.0.0.0] reference.  It's inside of Microsoft.Office.Core and gets added when I add in a reference for Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library

Comment: remove just office 14.0.0.0 reference as it is for office 2010

Comment: I updated my question above for clarification.  I see those references which I right click and select View in Object Browser.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by adding the Excel reference from the COM menu when it should have been added from the Assemblies menu.  Once the Excel COM reference was removed and the Excel Assemblies reference was added the error went away.